# Calling and passing API data to other component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call all API in Specific component "API.js", and  I want to Share Json data to other components, in the below example I am using Promise to share JSON, but I want to share data without promises if it is possible then tell me?

```
                                                 API.js File
import axios from "axios";
export async function TabelData() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    var res;
    console.log("Api Res=>", res);
    try {
      await axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=100",
      }).then(function (response) {
        res = response.data.results;
        console.log("Api Res", response);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
    resolve(res);
  });
}
                                                Search.js File
import { TabelData } from "../../../services/Api";
import "./Search.css";`enter code here`
const Search = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
  const [q, setQ] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    TabelData().then((res) => {
      setUserData(res);
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: You can't use axios without promises. Those calls are asynchronous, which is handled by promises.

Comment: Also note that wrapping an axios promise (*or any other method that returns a promise*) in a new Promise is an anti-pattern. Just adding needless code and complexity

Answer (score 1):

you might want to simplify TabelData function a bit as follows:

```
export async function TabelData() {
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=100"
    });
    return response.data.results;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this, but your main goal is to store the results in something that doesn't re-render when React is prompted to, like a React context (look at [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)).  Contexts let you store anything and retrieve them in any child component.

And, one library I like that does this very well by caching the results, is [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/).  You can use react-query on its own, or with another context.